# issue concerning ob_end_flush functions.php

Tags: plugins, php

I have this message at the bottom of my site:

> `ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0) in /home/cairopri/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4673`

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins and themes then turned them back on 1 by 1 to locate which contains the problem?

Comment: Please have a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693992/notice-ob-end-flush-failed-to-send-buffer-of-zlib-output-compression-1-in